# I have string ref and falied prop warnings in react with prototype and ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have these problems, and I don't know what to do. I don't know which way to go since I get these errors, I think it's because of the xFactor and the yFactor

Fullpage:

```
const Fullpagescroll = () => {
        <>
            <ReactFullpage
                scrollingSpeed={1150}
                recordHistory={true}
                anchors={['Home', 'About', 'Project', 'Contact']}
                navigation
                render={() => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            <div className='section' data-anchors='section1'>
                                <ItemHome
                                />
                            </div>
                        </>

Backgroundall: 

        const style = {
            bgLayerStyle: {
                position: 'absolute',
                right: 0,
                height: '100%',
            }
        }
        return (
            <ParallaxMousemove>
                <ul className='content-img'>
                    <li >
                        <ParallaxMousemove.Layer layerStyle={style.bgLayerStyle} config={{
                            xFactor: 0.06,
                            yFactor: 0.02,
                            springSettings: {
                                stiffness: 50,
                                damping: 10
                            }
                        }}>
                            <img src={LeftSide} alt='Background' />
                        </ParallaxMousemove.Layer>
```

[image]